How to fix a BeanCreationException for handlerExceptionResolver in Java Spring after upgrading to Spring Boot 3.x and Spring 6.x?
My application uses both Spring Boot and Spring dependencies. Due to a security vulnerability in spring-web, we have to update from 5.3.33 to 6.x. Currently we are using Spring Boot version 2.7.18, which uses the Spring Framework 5.x.
After updating the project from Java 11 to Java 17 and both the Spring boot starter parent and the more specific Spring Boot versions from 2.7.18 to 3.2.0 in the pom.xml, I finally updated spring-web from 5.3.33 to 6.0.19, and fixed some code incompatibilities between versions that were pointed out by the build process.
When trying to run the application with the command mvn spring-boot:run, the application builds successfully, but cannot start it. I get the following error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure /web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception with message: org/springframework/web/util/DisconnectedClientHelper
Googling, looking at similar questions and using AI suggested fixing the handlerExceptionResolver implementation within the project, but I don't have any implementation of said class.
Has any of you encountered this problem? If so, how did you solve it?
Cheers!
EDITS:
The pom.xml file can be found here: https://pastebin.com/rPDdckDQ
the full stacktrace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure
/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception with message: org/springframework/web/util/DisconnectedClientHelper
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:643) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]       
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:946) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]        
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) [spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) [spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) [spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) [spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) [spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at com.verint.useragentservice.UseragentServiceApplication.main(UseragentServiceApplication.java:16) [classes/:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) [spring-boot-devtools-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception with message: org/springframework/web/util/DisconnectedClientHelper
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:178) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/util/DisconnectedClientHelper
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.<clinit>(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1] 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.createExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:1079) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.createExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:554) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:1051) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1] 
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.DisconnectedClientHelper
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.<clinit>(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1] 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.createExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:1079) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.createExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:554) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:1051) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1] 
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
        ... 24 more


Why are you managing spring-web seperatly? You shouldn't do things like that. Which makes me wonder what you are even managing more. This feels like a case of trying to outsmart the spring boot dependency management already. Please add the full stacktrace as well instead of a snippet.

Thanks for the answer! I edited the question to include the full stacktrace. I am not very familiar with Spring's own dependency management; is there something we need to do to comply with Spring's dependency management? We have spring-boot-starter-parent set up currently, and more  spring-boot dependencies with version numbers controlled with one variable. The only non-spring boot dependency we have is spring-web.

Remove the spring-web dependency and please add your maven pom.xml as well. The fact that you have a classnotfound is generally due to outsmarting dependency management. As you already can see you are mixing versions with your spring-web dependency (you use 6.0.19, where the rest of SPring Boot rquires 6.1.1).

Please add the pom to the question not as a link in the comments.

Remove spring.version, remove the version tag from spring-boot-starter dependencies. Ditch junit dependendy and add spring-boot-starter-test. For cloud make sure it is compatible and you really should be using the spring cloud bom to manage that.

My question got answered in the comments but I thought I'd post a separate answer to highlight it:
"The fact that you have a classnotfound is generally due to outsmarting dependency management. As you already can see you are mixing versions with your spring-web dependency (you use 6.0.19, where the rest of Spring Boot requires 6.1.1).".
So I cleaned up the pom.xml from redundant dependencies and versions and changed the spring-web dependency to 6.1.1.
